# Finding the biggest value of key-value list

Tags: haskell

Hey guys I am trying to build a program where check which pair have the biggest value and returned within a list 
for example vector **[(60,3),(10,4),(5,30)] returns [(5,30)]**
This is what I am thinking:

```
vector :: Ord a => [(t, a)] -> [(t, a)]
vector (x:xs) = maxTail x xs
  where maxTail currentMax [] = currentMax
        maxTail (m, n) (p:ps)
          | n < (snd p) = maxTail p ps
          | otherwise   = maxTail (m, n) ps
```

the error is **Couldn't match expected type**

Comment: That's not the complete error. Post *complete* error.

Comment: You may do like `maximumBy (comparing snd) [(60,3),(10,4),(5,30)]` whereas `maximumBy` lives in the `Data.List` and `comparing` lives in the `Data.Ord` packages.

Comment: Read the error more closely. It is "couldn't match expected type <some type> with actual type <different type>", and it tells you which expression is causing the problem.  This often gets you a long way toward seeing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`maxTail` returns a pair (the maximum one), while `vector`'s type promises to return a list of pairs. Hence the mismatch. The full type error (which was not posted) should have provided this as a hint.

Do you really need to return a list? There is only one pair returned, so I would change `vector`'s type to be `.... -> (t, a)` instead.